# Universal definition of vertically mirrored triangles on top of each other

Tags: stacking-symbols

In this question, we try to get two unfilled triangles on top of one another, mirrored vertically, as a relation symbol. Here is what we've tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand{\hasTypeA}[1]{
  \mathrel{\raisebox{.3ex}{\scalebox{.55}{\(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{3}{\vartriangle}{\triangledown}\)}}}
}
\newcommand{\hasTypeB}[1]{
  \mathrel{\raisebox{.3ex}{\scalebox{.55}{\(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{3}{\triangledown}{\vartriangle}\)}}}
}
\begin{document}\noindent
\(\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}\ {}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}}\ {}^{{}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}}}\)
\[\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}\ {}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}}\ {}^{{}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}}}\]
\(\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}\ {}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}}\ {}^{{}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}}}\)
\[\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}\ {}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}}\ {}^{{}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}}}\]
\todo[inline]{%
\(\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}\ {}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}}\ {}^{{}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}}}\)
\[\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}\ {}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}}\ {}^{{}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}}}\]
\(\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}\ {}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}}\ {}^{{}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}}}\)
\[\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}\ {}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}}\ {}^{{}^{\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}}}\]
}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `xelatex` yields

[image: after edit]

As you see, this result suffers from several problems.

First, the two triangles are rather far apart; it would be nicer to have them a little bit closer together at least in `\hasTypeA` and perhaps in `\hasTypeB` (but not as close as in ⧖ or ⟠). Second, they don't scale in (sub)subscripts and (super)superscripts.  Third, the solution works only for `xelatex`, and for `lualatex` it gets ugly, and we'd need to do something different for `pdflatex` anyway.

While I would probably be able to provide a huge font-dependent definition with `\mathpalette`, `\ifxetex`, `\ifluatex`, `stmaryrd`, and, if necessary, `tikz`, it won't be nice or simple.  Is there anything universal and simple at the same time, perhaps?  Or has anyone done the huge dirty job so far in their papers and would like to share their attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this should be a `\mathrel`. Anyway, for the script styles I chose to add some sidebearings with `\nonscript\mkern-6mu\mkern6mu` (the `\nonscript` only has effect in `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle`, so it will cancel out the kerns).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hasTypeA}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \nonscript\mkern-2mu\mkern2mu
    \mathpalette\hasType@AB{\vartriangle\triangledown}%
    \nonscript\mkern-2mu\mkern2mu
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hasTypeB}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \nonscript\mkern-2mu\mkern2mu
    \mathpalette\hasType@AB{\triangledown\vartriangle}%
    \nonscript\mkern-2mu\mkern2mu
  }%
}
\newcommand{\hasType@AB}[2]{\hasType@@AB#1#2}
\newcommand{\hasType@@AB}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1x$}%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\z@}{%
    \vbox{%
      \ialign{%
        ##\cr
        $\m@th#1#2$\cr
        \noalign{\nointerlineskip\vskip0.4pt}%
        $\m@th#1#3$\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\(
  \mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}
  \scriptstyle\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}
  \scriptscriptstyle\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}
\)

\(
  \mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}
  \scriptstyle\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}
  \scriptscriptstyle\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}
\)

\(\displaystyle
  \mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}
  \scriptstyle\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}
  \scriptscriptstyle\mathit{var}\hasTypeA\mathit{Type}
\)

\(\displaystyle
  \mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}
  \scriptstyle\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}
  \scriptscriptstyle\mathit{var}\hasTypeB\mathit{Type}
\)

\todo[inline]{$\hasTypeA$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Just_A_Man Reduced the height.

Comment: @Just_A_Man Use `\DeclareRobustCommand` as in the new code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the gap, edit the `4pt`.  If you want to change the overall height, change the `{X}` to something with a different vertical footprint (possibly a `\rule` expressed in `ex` measurement)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
    uptri/.style={
        draw,
        ultra thick,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
    }
}
\tikzset{
    dntri/.style={
        draw,
        shape border rotate=180,
        ultra thick,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
    }
}
\savestack\uptri{\tikz{\node[uptri]{}}}
\savestack\dntri{\tikz{\node[dntri]{}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\outtri{\mathrel{\scalerel*{%
  \stackengine{4pt}{\dntri}{\uptri}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{X}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\intri{\mathrel{\scalerel*{%
  \stackengine{4pt}{\uptri}{\dntri}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{X}}}
\begin{document}
$x \outtri Type\qquad x \intri Type$

$\scriptstyle x \outtri Type\qquad x \intri Type$

$\scriptscriptstyle x \outtri Type\qquad x \intri Type$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For example, redefining the overall height to the footprint of `x` rather than `X`, by way of

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\outtri{\mathrel{\scalerel*{%
  \stackengine{4pt}{\dntri}{\uptri}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{x}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\intri{\mathrel{\scalerel*{%
  \stackengine{4pt}{\uptri}{\dntri}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{x}}}
```

changes the result thus:

[image]

Comment: @Just_A_Man I chose `tikz` approach because I could easily make triangles with no space buffers above/below.  With normal glyphs, there is surrounding space, which can adversely affect the layout of the "stack", especially if multiple math styles (sizes) are involved.

Comment: @Just_A_Man Also, `unicode-math` precludes the use of `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Just_A_Man I merely used `\DeclareRobustCommand`, rather than `\newcommand`, to make `\intri` and `\outtri` work with `todonotes`.  I also used a `\savestack` rather than `\newcommand` for the underlying `\uptri` and `\dntri`. This saves having to re-render the `tikz` with each use, but instead saves the typeset image in a savebox.

Comment: @Just_A_Man Your call.  Neither of us will be offended, whoever you choose.