# Is this IPA symbol for a long vowel available?

Tags: symbols, linguistics

Is the below marked symbol available in any of the font?

[image]

Comment: I'd say `\textlengthmark` from the `tipa` package, though the common Times-like fonts seem to differ slightly.

Comment: Don't hesitate to use [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) when looking for a symbol!

Comment: @campa Your suggestion works nicely, can you make this as answer? Also thanks to @Eneveve` for suggesting about `Detexify`...

Comment: It is U+02D0 MODIFIER LETTER TRIANGULAR COLON -- aː eː iː `^^^^02d0`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As commented by campa, below might be a solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
p\^{e}l /pe\textlengthmark l/
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Unicode, it is triangular colon (U+02D0):

[image: lengthmarkb]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\ffontaname{DejaVu Serif}
\newcommand\ffontbname{Gentium Plus}
\newcommand\ffontcname{FreeMono} 
\newcommand\ffontdname{Doulos SIL}
\newcommand\ffontename{FreeSerif}
\newcommand\ffontfname{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\ffonta{\ffontaname}
\newfontfamily\ffontb{\ffontbname}
\newfontfamily\ffontc{\ffontcname} 
\newfontfamily\ffontd{\ffontdname}
\newfontfamily\ffonte{\ffontename}
\newfontfamily\ffontf{\ffontfname}

\newcommand\testtext{pêl /peːl/}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\ffontaname & \ffonta\testtext \\
\ffontbname & \ffontb\testtext \\
\ffontcname & \ffontc\testtext \\
\ffontdname & \ffontd\testtext \\
\ffontename & \ffonte\testtext \\
\ffontfname & \ffontf\testtext \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add [Doulos SIL](https://ctan.org/pkg/doulossil) & [Charis SIL](https://ctan.org/pkg/charissil) as they are specifically designed for IPA.

Comment: @Niranjan Done. See amended answer.

Comment: Thanks! Your answers always show a good range of available font-options. I find them very resourceful.

Answer (score 6):

Adapting my answer at [Universal definition of vertically mirrored triangles on top of each other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550655/universal-definition-of-vertically-mirrored-triangles-on-top-of-each-other)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
    uptri/.style={fill,
        draw,
        ultra thick,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
        xscale=.7
    }
}
\tikzset{
    dntri/.style={fill,
        draw,
        shape border rotate=180,
        ultra thick,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
        xscale=.7
    }
}
\savestack\uptri{\tikz{\node[uptri]{}}}
\savestack\dntri{\tikz{\node[dntri]{}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\intri{\kern.5pt\scalerel*{%
  \stackengine{9pt}{\uptri}{\dntri}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{e}\kern.5pt}
\begin{document}
p\^el /pe\intri l/
\end{document}
```

[image]