# How to create this IPA phonetic chart in LaTeX

Tags: tables, phonetic

This is the table I used as inspiration. I don't need the same layout but I want you to make an idea:

[image]

I don't need the example words below the symbols, the ones like "bean", "moon", "dear", etc..

This is what I created in LaTeX so far using `tabular`:
I added all the boxes for all the symbols I will need. So, this is the final number of cells:

[image]

However I would like to create something like this:

[image]

I want the circled letters in gray, not black.

Also, I would like to have the title "English IPA Chart" or just "IPA Chart" if there is not enough space on the right side where there is empty space with two examples below.

I would like some spacing between the tables as well and make the bold `\hline` horizontal lines black and let the others horizontal and vertical lines in light gray like they're now.

This is my LaTeX Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}

\geometry{a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.8}

\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}}
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\Large The Simple Vowels}\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
        \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont a & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont c & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont e & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont g & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont i & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont k\\ 
        \hline
        \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont b & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont d & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont f & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont h & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont j & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont l\\ 
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}}
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\Large The Diphthongs}\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
        \huge aa & \huge bb & \huge cc & \huge dd & \huge ee\\ 
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
    \end{tabular}\\\\

    \begin{tabular}{P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large Stop Consonants}\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}%
        \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont a & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont c & \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont e\\ 
        \hline
        \huge b & \huge d & \huge f\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{P{5em}|P{5em}}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\Large Continuant Consonants}\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
        \huge a & \huge c\\ 
        \hline
        \huge b & \huge d\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large The Sibilant Sounds}\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
        \huge a & \huge c & \huge e\\ 
        \hline
        \huge b & \huge d & \huge f\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
    \end{tabular}\\\\

    \begin{tabular}{P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large The Glide Sounds}\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
        \huge a & & & &\\ 
        \hline
        & \huge b & \huge c & \huge d & \huge e\\ 
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{P{5em}|P{5em}|P{5em}}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large The Nasal Sounds}\\
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
        & & \\ 
        \hline
        \huge a & \huge b & \huge c\\ 
        \specialrule{1.6pt}{1pt}{1pt}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I would be grateful for any help. I don't necessarily need that "VOWELS" and "CONSONANT" column with the vertical text. Even if you could just give me some hints or some sample code (not full code) how can I start or proceed I would be grateful.

Comment: With a Unicode font, you can type directly: `ʀ ʁ ʂ ʃ ʄ ʅ ʆ ʇ ʈ ʉ ʊ ɐ ɑ ɒ ɓ ɔ` etc. With color, you can use the `\color{...}` switch, or `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}` command. Indirectly, you can type glyph slot `^^^^0259` (hex) or `\symbol{601}` (decimal) or `\symbol{"0259}` (hex) to get ` ə`.

Comment: For triangular colon, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610854/is-this-ipa-symbol-for-a-long-vowel-available/610871#610871

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm using the Charis SIL with XeLaTex and I can type out the symbols without the need of the `TIPA` package. In fact, I prefer typing them out because I wrote a custom input method for Emacs that allows me to type out IPA characters easily from the keyboard.

Comment: @ZoltanKing sorry for an absolutely unrelated query with respect to this question, but is your code for the custom input method on GNU-Emacs released? I would love to go through the code for my personal learning. I am also trying to achieve something similar, not for IPA, but for other another script. Feel free to contact me on _hi (dot) niranjan (at) pm (dot) me_.

Comment: It's a function I load with `CTRL+u CTRL+ backslash` then if I want to type the schwa symbol I just type `\uh`.  https://github.com/zoliky/dotemacs#custom-input-methods

Comment: @ZoltanKing Thanks a lot.